# Writing generic algorithms while avoiding std::function C++

Tags: c++, functional-programming, compilation

I have written a generic piece of code that takes a set of `std::function`s as arguments.

```
void algorithm(function f, function g,...) {
    ...
    f(...)
    ...
    g(...)
    ....
}
```

Function f can be chosen from a set of functions (f1,f2,...) and g from a set of functions (g1,g2,..) with the same signature. Is there a way to automatically compile `algorithm` multiple times for multiple sets of arguments?

So, one version `algorithm_f1_g2` compiled with `f=f1` and `g=g1` and so on.

I have already tried to use macros for this but I did not get very far.

PS: I really do want this generic behavior *at compile time*, for maximum speed.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're ok with limiting the functions to some predefined set (meaning we don't have to worry about supporting lambdas or arbitrary functors), you can implement `algorithm` as a [function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template) with [function-pointer parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter):

```cpp
// Known signature for 'algorithm' parameters.
using AlgoFunction = void (*)(int);

// Set of predetermined parameter functions.
void f1(int){ /* ... */ }
void f2(int){ /* ... */ }
void ga(int){ /* ... */ }
void gb(int){ /* ... */ }

template <AlgoFunction f, AlgoFunction g>
void algorithm()
{
    // ...
    f(1);
    // ...
    g(2);
    // ...
}
```

which can be used as

```
algorithm<f1, ga>();
```

Optionally, you can even given names to particular specializations. For example,

```
constexpr auto algorithm_1a = algorithm<f1, ga>;

int main() {
    algorithm_1a();
}
```

Comment: I like your answer more than I do my own! Although, in your case, the calls to `algorithm` are a *wee* bit clunkier, your code allows that `constexpr auto algorithm_1a` assignment.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template) for this:

```cpp
template<class T, class U>
void algorithm(T f, U g)
{
    f();
    g();
}
```

Then, when you add any call to your `algorithm` in your code, the compiler will create an instance for the template (an *actual* function) using the arguments you provide in the generated code:

```cpp
void f1()
{
    std::cout << "f1\n";
}

void f2()
{
    std::cout << "f2\n";
}

void g1()
{
    std::cout << "g1\n";
}

void g2()
{
    std::cout << "g2\n";
}

int main()
{
    algorithm(f1, g1); 
    algorithm(f2, g2); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest one rather minor change. Using pointers to functions can prevent generating inline code for those functions. It often works out better if you use a lambda expression instead.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Agreed. However, those template calls resolve to actually using pointers to functions as it stands.

Comment: *"these two lines will generate TWO DIFFERENT functions"*. No, in both cases, it is `algorithm<void(*)(), void(*)()>`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, you are correct. I've removed that comment but will now need to think a bit more about this proposed answer.